# Determine $c>0$ such that $\frac 13 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-\frac4n}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{9-\frac{1}{n}}} \ge \frac{c}{n}$ for all positive integer $n$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to show that there exists some constant $c>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac 13 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-\frac4n}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{9-\frac{1}{n}}} \ge \frac{c}{n},
\end{align*}
holds for any positive integer $n$ (or at least $n$ large enough). The constant does not necessarily have to be tight.

Mathematica gives $c=1/27$ but I do not see how to arrive at the solution.

*Attempt:*
As a first step, assume that $c=1/27$ is known and we just want to verify that the inequality holds. Then, continuing by brute-force
\begin{align*}
\frac 13 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-\frac4n}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{9-\frac{1}{n}}} &\ge \frac{1}{27n}, \\
1 + \frac{3}{\sqrt{9-\frac4n}}-\frac{6}{\sqrt{9-\frac{1}{n}}} &\ge \frac{1}{9n}, \\
\sqrt{9-\frac4n}\sqrt{9-\frac1n} + 3\sqrt{9-\frac1n}-6\sqrt{9-\frac{4}{n}} &\ge \frac{1}{9n}\sqrt{9-\frac1n}\sqrt{9-\frac4n}, \\
\sqrt{\frac{9n-4}{n}}\sqrt{\frac{9n-1}{n}} + 3\sqrt{\frac{9n-1}{n}}-6\sqrt{\frac{9n-4}{n}} &\ge \frac{1}{9n}\sqrt{\frac{9n-1}{n}}\sqrt{\frac{9n-4}{n}}, \\
\sqrt{9n-4}\sqrt{9n-1} + 3\sqrt{n}\sqrt{9n-1}-6\sqrt{n}\sqrt{9n-4} &\ge \frac{1}{9n}\sqrt{9n-1}\sqrt{9n-4}, \\
\end{align*}
and the only direct way forward is to rearrange and to square both sides. One obtains
\begin{align*}
\left[\sqrt{9n-4}\sqrt{9n-1} + 3\sqrt{n}\sqrt{9n-1}\right]^2 &\ge \left[\frac{1}{9n}\sqrt{9n-1}\sqrt{9n-4} + 6\sqrt{n}\sqrt{9n-4}\right]^2, \\
(9n-4)(9n-1)+6\sqrt{9n-4}\sqrt{9n-1}\sqrt{9n-1}\sqrt{n}+9n(9n-1) &\ge \frac{1}{81n^2}(9n-1)(9n-4)+2\cdot 6\frac{1}{9n}\sqrt{9n-1}\sqrt{9n-4}\sqrt{9n-4}\sqrt{n}+36n(9n-4).
\end{align*}
The roots in the respective middle two expression of the binomial equations cancel and we are left with
\begin{align*}
(9n-4)(9n-1)+6\sqrt{9n-4}(9n-1)\sqrt{n}+9n(9n-1) &\ge \frac{1}{81n^2}(9n-1)(9n-4)+2\cdot 6\frac{1}{9n}\sqrt{9n-1}(9n-4)\sqrt{n}+36n(9n-4).
\end{align*}
Neither expanding the parenthesis nor factoring out $(9n-1)$ and $(9n-4)$, respectively, allows dropping the remaining roots and I do not know how to continue to show that the inequality is satisfied.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by solve? There are two variables and this is an inequality. Do you need the tightest possible bound for the left-side expression that is in the form of the right-side expression?

Comment: I want to show that the l.h.s. (as a function of $n$) is lower bounded by the function $c/n$, where $c$ is a constant. Optimally the constant is tight.

Comment: @Flo, if you want us to help you, you have to write your attempts and efforts in order to solve your problem, otherwise your post will be closed very soon, indeed in this siteweb “no clue” problems are not accepted.

Comment: You need to try *something* and show what you have tried in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I put the "brute-force" approach that I tried above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=1/n$. We show that
$$f(x)=\frac13+\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-4x}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{9-x}}> \frac{x}{27}$$
whenever $0<x<\frac94$. We have $f(0)=0$, and
$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{2}{(9-4x)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{(9-x)^{3/2}}\\
&>\frac{2}{(9-x)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{(9-x)^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{(9-x)^{3/2}}\\
&>\frac{1}{9^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{27}
\end{align}$$
which is what we wanted. So:

- your expression is true with $c=\frac{1}{27}$ for $\frac49<n<\infty$, which includes all positive integers $n$;
- $f'(0)=\frac{1}{27}$, so $\frac{1}{27}$ is the best you can hope for (because for small positive $x$, we have $f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+O(x^2)=f(0)+\frac{x}{27}+O(x^2)$, so if $c$ were greater than $\frac{1}{27}$, $f(x)$ would be less than $f(0)+cx$ for small enough positive $x$).

Comment: Same answer I got but simpler. Upvoted.

Comment: @martycohen: not quite the same answer! This shows that the inequality is true for _all_ integers $n$, not just for sufficiently large ones.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on your second remark? Why does the value of the derivative at 0 give me the tightest constant?

Comment: @Flo: I have added a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$x=\frac1{n}$.
Want
$\frac 13 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-4x}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{9-x}} \ge cx
$.

Now use the
generalized binomial theorem
in the form
$(1+x)^{-1/2}
=1 + x/2  + O(x^2)
$.

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\frac 13 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-4x}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{9-x}}\\
&=\frac 13 + (9-4x)^{-1/2}-2(9-x)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac 13 + \frac13(1-4x/9)^{-1/2}-\frac23(1-x/9)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac 13\left(1 + (1-4x/9)^{-1/2}-2(1-x/9)^{-1/2}\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(1 + (1+\frac{4x}{9\cdot 2}+O(x^2))-2(1+\frac{x}{9\cdot 2}+O(x^2)\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(\frac{2x}{9}-\frac{x}{9}+O(x^2)\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(\frac{2x}{9}-\frac{x}{9}+O(x^2)\right)\\
&=\frac{x}{27}+O(x^2)\\
\end{array}
$

So we need
$c \le \frac1{27}
$.

To determine if
$c=\frac1{27}
$
works, we need another term
in the form
$(1+x)^{-1/2}
=1 + x/2 +3x^2/8 + O(x^3)
$.

This becomes

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\frac 13 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-4x}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{9-x}}\\
&=\frac 13 + (9-4x)^{-1/2}-2(9-x)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac 13 + \frac13(1-4x/9)^{-1/2}-\frac23(1-x/9)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac 13\left(1 + (1-4x/9)^{-1/2}-2(1-x/9)^{-1/2}\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(1 + (1+\frac{4x}{9\cdot 2}+\frac38\frac{(4x)^2}{9^2}+O(x^3))-2(1+\frac{x}{9\cdot 2}+\frac38\frac{(x)^2}{9^2}+O(x^3)\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(\frac{2x}{9}+\frac38\frac{16x^2}{81})-\frac{x}{9}-\frac34\frac{x^2}{81}+O(x^3)\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(\frac{2x}{9}+\frac{2x^2}{27}-\frac{x}{9}-\frac{x^2}{4\cdot 27}+O(x^3)\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(\frac{x}{9}+x^2(\frac{2}{27}-\frac1{4\cdot 27})+O(x^3)\right)\\
&=\frac 13\left(\frac{x}{9}+\frac{7x^2}{4\cdot 27}+O(x^3)\right)\\
&=\frac{x}{27}+\frac{7x^2}{324}+O(x^3)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f(x)
\gt \frac{x}{27}$
for small $x$.

Wolfram Alpha gives
$f(x)
=x/27 + (7 x^2)/324 + (155 x^3)/17496 + (4445 x^4)/1259712 + (3577 x^5)/2519424 + O(x^6)
$
which is comforting.

Comment: Thank you very much! Greatly appreciated.